# Construct std::set from array

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, set

Why doesn't C++ provide us with a constructor which takes an array as an argument? Alternatively, is there anything wrong with defining the following function?

```
template <class T>
std::set<T> ArrayToSet(T array[]) {
  return std::set<T>(array, array + sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));
}
```

I think the answer might come down to ideas of dynamic memory allocation, but I'd like to hear some feedback on this.

**Edit:** I am not using C++11.

Comment: Use the iterator one.

Comment: " is there anything wrong with defining the following function?" Yes, it's 100% wrong, always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Alternatively, is there anything wrong with defining the following function?

There is: it doesn’t work.

You cannot pass variable-length C-style arrays to functions. The `T array[]` syntax in an argument list is a synonym for `T* array`: a *raw pointer* is passed, not an argument.

You can, however, pass fixed-sized arrays by reference (i.e. `T (&array)[5]` works). To make this work for different array lengths you need to use a non-type template argument:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
std::set<T> ArrayToSet(T (&array)[N]) {
  return std::set<T>(array, array + N);
}
```

– But I agree in this with Zac: the function is over-specific (or, the other way round: not generic enough). There is already a universal collection-construction method, via iterators. So the correct way is to use C++11’s `std::begin` and `std::end` facility, and if you cannot use C++11, then the correct way is to write them yourself:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* begin(T (&array)[N]) {
    return array;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T (&array)[N]) {
    return array + N;
}
```

Comment: Might be good to show usage as well: `std::set<T>(begin(array),end(array))`.

Comment: There seems to be consensus that creating begin() and end() functions is the correct answer to the problem, rather than a conversion function.

Answer (score 5):

> Why doesn't C++ provide us with a constructor which takes an array as
>   an argument?

Why would it?  A `std::set` is not an array, and it already has a constructor that takes iterators to initialize it, so adding another constructor for an array is unnecessary.  `std::vector` IS an array and even it does not have a constructor that takes an array.

> Alternatively, is there anything wrong with defining the following
>   function?

Yes and no.  It is unnecessary as you can just write

```
MyType myArray[mySize];
std::set<MyType> mySet(myArray, myArray + sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(array[0]);
// or std::set<MyType> mySet(myArray, myArray + mySize);
// or std::set<MyType> mySet(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray)); c++11
```

It isn't really worthy of its own function.

If you really want to write a function to help you out, I'd approach it by porting `std::begin` and `std::end` to C++03.  Those would at least be more usable than a function specifically to create a `std::set`.

It would look exactly like what Konrad posted in his answer.

Comment: It totally *is* worth its own function, but OP’s function doesn’t work.

Comment: Fair enough about why there isn't a constructor. The reason I wanted this function is that I plan to do this a lot, and having a function saves typos. I would love to be able to use C++11 initialiser lists, but that's not an option...

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  Do you plan to write a 1 line function for every variable type you declare?  Good Lord, I hope to never have to view your code ...

Comment: @Zac Excuse me, why the hostility? And I happen to think that you would be extremely lucky to review my code since I’m confident that it’s in the upper percentile of the quality distribution. And to answer your question: no, of course I don’t. But the syntax to retrieve an iterator range for an array is complex and error-prone – why do you think does C++11 specialise `std::begin` and `std::end` for arrays? I’m not in favour of an `ArrayToSet` function, but *something* to avoid the convoluted computation of the array’s end is definitely worthwhile.

Comment: @DavidHall:  Hence the reason I said "yes and no".  You really aren't saving yourself much typing by placing it in a function, and you are reducing readability ... but in the end, your binary code will be the same, so it won't make much of a difference.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  Apparently the sarcasm didn't get conveyed well.  My point was simply that if you were going to write a function for every type you wanted to define (in addition to the constructors which are already written), you'd be obfuscating the code unnecessarily and making your code much less readable.

Comment: Ok, I didn't want to cause an argument. I'm not planning to do this for every case, but just this specific case as a way to emulate the initialiser lists in C++11 (albeit with an additional line).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: C++11 specialized `std::begin` and `std::end` because arrays don't have members, so we could write generic "container" code that worked on arrays.  Had nothing to do with preventing errors when writing `array+len` IMO>

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, IMO, you’re wrong. you can *already* work with arrays as if they were containers, just write `array, array + sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`. But like I said this is rather convoluted. And no, this has nothing to do with member functions or the lack thereof.

Comment: The added code doesn’t work by the way, `sizeof` of a pointer returns the pointer’s size, not an array size.

Comment: It works if the array is declared statically (e.g. `int i[100];`  It just doesn't work for dynamically sized arrays (e.g. `int* i = new int[100];`).  You've already posted the more complete way to handle that, so I'll leave this answer as-is.

Answer (score 3):

`std::set` does not need to provide a constructor for C style arrays, because it is possible to construct from them already using iterators - furthermore it is not easy to construct from an array, because you could try to construct from `T *`, which does not convey the array length, or whether it's an array at all.

To do this, we use a template trick to determine the array size and use the iterator constructor:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
std::set<T> ArrayToSet(T (& array)[N]) {
    return std::set<T>(&array[0], &array[0]+N);
}
```

Note that, as stated in the comments, this will not work for `T *` types. You could overload for that giving an additional parameter `arr_length` or something. In this case `sizeof` doesn't work either, it would just give you the size of the pointer, not the array.

Comment: I've updated to state I'm not using C++11. Could you please explain why we need to be "sneaky"? Thanks

Comment: For the non-C++11 version, I would implement `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Unless I've missed something in the latest standard, template parameters need to be completely determinable at compile time, so the template version here will work as long as you know the size ahead of time, but will not work for dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: @ZacHowland That's correct; and a good reason why you would want to use `std::vector` instead

Comment: `&array[N]` is **invalid**. You are not allowed to access `array[N]`, even if you take the pointer immediately after. In at least some versions of VC++ this fails at runtime, and probably in other compilers as well.

Comment: As Konrad pointed out, the return should look something like `return std::set<T>(array, array + (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])));`